# Load Shaders using an Object Orientated Approach

Tags: c++, string, opengl

My Application is going to be an OpenGL Game using `OpenGL 4.2`, `GLFW` and `GLEW`. The Problem is about loading GLSL shaders from file. I use a class named `ShadersObject` for all shader related tasks.

```
class ShadersObject
{
public:
    // ...
private:
    // ...
    void LoadFile(string Name, string Path);
    string FolderPath;
    Shaders ShaderList;
};
```

The class uses a map of `ShaderObject`s to store the shaders.

```
enum ShaderType{ Vertex = GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                 Geometry = GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER,
                 Fragment = GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER };

struct ShaderObject
{
    const GLchar* File;
    ShaderType Type;
    GLuint Shader;
    // ...
};

typedef map<string, ShaderObject> Shaders;
```

The following method I should load the source code of the GLSL shader from a file to the `ShaderObject` in `ShaderList`. Therefore it uses the `Path` to the file and the `Name` of the shader as the string key in the `ShaderList` map is named.

```
void ShadersObject::LoadFile(string Name, string Path)
{
    string FilePath = FolderPath + Path;
    ifstream Stream(FilePath);

    if(Stream.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Loading Shader from " << FilePath << endl;

        string Output;
        Stream.seekg(0, ios::end);   
        Output.reserve(Stream.tellg());
        Stream.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        Output.assign((istreambuf_iterator<char>(Stream)),istreambuf_iterator<char>());

        // this line doesn't compile
        strcpy(ShaderList[Name].File, Output.c_str());
    }
    else cout << "Can not load Shader from " << FilePath << endl;
}
```

I another method I want to use the value from `ShaderList[Name].File` to load and compile the shaders using `glShaderSource` and `glCompileShader`. Where `glShaderSource` needs a pointer to a `const GLchar*` holding the source code. In my case this would be `&ShaderList[Name].File`.

Some time ago I used `ShaderList[Name].File = Output.c_str();` instead of the line which doesn't compile now. The result was that only the pointer was saved in the `ShaderList` and after the method exited the source code was gone. That's why I tried using `strcpy` but this function doesn't accept `const GLchar*` as parameter type.

**How can I save the read file into my class member?**

Comment: Why not store it as a `std::string` in `ShaderObject` and use `c_str()` when necessary? If you want to use `strcpy()` you need to allocate memory for `.File` and make it non-`const`.

Comment: Thanks, I can't understand why I havn't tried it before?! Simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complex problem: *store the string*. Store `Output` in your `ShadersObject` class. When you need to call `glShaderSource`, then convert it into a `const GLchar*` with `string::c_str`.

Or better yet; don't store either of them; OpenGL will retain the shader string in the shader object. You can query the shader strings from OpenGL via the API. So there's really no point in your shader object storing what OpenGL already stores.

Comment: Does OpenGL also store the type of the shader so that I can query it?

Comment: @sharethis: You could [check the documentation](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetShader).

Comment: Thanks, so I only need to store the string name and the OpenGL int name and if the shader is active. Thank you again! **Edit:** I want to store the source code so that I can toggle shaders on and off. **Can you give me an advice if this is clever?**

Comment: @sharethis: Storing source code won't help with that. Once a program is linked, what you do to the shaders that comprise it is irrelevant unless you *re-link* the program. And that's expensive. So no.

Comment: Ok, i go with storing the file path now :-)

Comment: @sharethis. Switching on and of shader *programs* is done by binding/unbinding them. If you separate shader and program classes you can do, what the OpenGL API allows and link a single shader into multiple programs, where each may consist of a different set of shaders. This is usefull for example for using the same vertex transformations, but different fragment shaders (shadow buffer calculation, vs. final rendering pass, or similar).

Comment: @datenwolf. Thanks for you explaination and greetings from Germany.